# How to get user info on the server side of a website which is using kerberos?

Tags: jsp, kerberos, userinfo

The kerberos provide authentication control, but I still need to have some user-wise control so I want to get more user information(eg. uid). Thanks.

Comment: Where is the connection between the subject and the body? I see none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available by [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29).

So, in a servlet it would look like:

```
String name = request.getRemoteUser();
// ...
```

In a JSP it would look like:

```
<p>Welcome, ${pageContext.request.remoteUser}</p>
```

Comment: `request.remoteUser` is shorter and does the same.

Comment: @Michael: it only returns `null` for Kerberos/LDAP.

Comment: Then the principal is null. `getRemoteUser` is just a short-hand for the call above. There must be some bug in **your** code. I have a custom kerberos authenticator in Tomcat which works as desired. You should attach to tomcat and debug it.

Comment: @Michael: we aren't using it anywhere. It's just what I've read on forums over last decade. As you're so confident that it works, I've edited the answer :)

Comment: Absolutely confident, see [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.14/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#2124) for the original tomcat code.

Comment: It works for me, I found similar answer somewhere else. Thanks for your answer.